# Вопрос по Logback и конфигурационному файлу

Tags: логирование

В конфигурационном файле есть строки: 
`<Logger name = "Ru.we.RR" level="debug"/>` и ещё
`<root level = "info">`. Что означают эти строки?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галочка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В **Logback** есть понятие **Logger**. **Logger** это объект с помощью которого осуществляется логирование. У него есть несколько методов при помощи которых можно создать записи с различным уровнем. Уровень это параметр позволяющий описать важность того или иного сообщения. В **Logback** есть следующие увровни:

- TRACE (самый высокий)
- DEBUG
- INFO
- WARN
- ERROR
- FATAL (самый низкий)

Каждый **Logger** можете быть настроен на фильтрацию записей определенного уровня. Если если уровень записи выше уровня **Logger**, то данная запись будет проигнорирована.

Все **Logger** организованны в древовидную иерархию. Корневой **Logger** носит название `root`. Разработчик может добавлять свои **Logger** в иерархию. Место **Logger** в иерархии зависит от его имени. Например, **Logger** с именем `Ru.we.RR` является находиться в поддереве у `Ru.we`, тот в свою очередь в поддереве `Ru` и завершает все `root`. Если у **Logger** не установлен уровень, то он берет уровень своего предка.

`<root level = "info">` - означает, что у `root` (корень дерева) будет установлен уровень **INFO** и этот уровень будет и потомков, если он не будет установлен явно в конфигурационном файле. `<Logger name = "Ru.we.RR" level="debug"/>` - означает, что у `Ru.we.RR` и у его потомков будет уровень **DEBUG**.

Какие уровни выбирать при использовании **Logger** в коде зависит от правил, которые приняты в группе разработчиков. Но я обычно пользуюсь следующим вариантом:

- FATAL - это "предсмертное" сообщение, после этого система завершает свою работу
- ERROR - ошибки во входных данных, которые невозможно исправить. В сообщении должны быть эти входные данные.
- WARN - ошибки во входных данных, которые возможно исправить, например, используется устаревший (deprecated) тип входного параметра.
- INFO - почти не использую
- DEBUG - информация о каждом "чихе" внутри системы, получил что-то на входе - записали в лог, посчитали что-то - записали в лог
- TRACE - почти не использую

Comment: Ещё бы про смысл уровней пару слов или ссылку, а то их вечно используют как попало (по крайней мере, в моём опыте). :)

Comment: вы имеете ввиду какая разница между, например WARN и ERROR?

Comment: да, например так.

Comment: Очень крутое объяснение) благодарю вас за супер развернутый ответ)))! Есть ещё один момент <contextListener class="ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator"> 
 <resetJUL>true</resetJUL> 
 </contextListener> 
 
 <!— To enable JMX Management —> 
 <jmxConfigurator/>

Comment: Для чего contextlistener и resetjul? В доках пишется про java utill logging, но не догоню что именно, Инглиш пока хромает слегка(

Comment: Если у Вас возник новый вопрос, задайте его при помощи кнопки [Задать вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Если нужно указать контекст, дайте ссылку на этот вопрос.

Comment: @NickVolynkin дополнил ответ своим видением уровней